# Redis-server closed when using redis-benchmark

Tags: docker, redis

I am using `redis-benchmark` on Ubuntu by using docker container.

I am experimenting performance of memory and CPU by limiting resources by Docker.

For example:

```
docker run --cpus="2" -m=4M -it [imageID]
```

My image is based on `ubntu:latest` and installed `redis-server`.

So, when I get into a container I run `redis-server` on background and use `redis-benchmark`:

```
10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
Background saving started by pid 17
DB saved on disk
RDB: 0MB of memory used by copy-on-write
Background saving terminated with success
Error: Server closed the connection
[1]+ Killed    redis-server
```

An error shows up.

My `redis-benchmark` command to make key/value size 100000:

```
redis-benchmark -q -r 100000 -c 1
```

If this is because of limitation of memory size, I think this command:

```
redis-benchamrk -c 1 -r 100000 -n 400
```

should also shut down the `redis-server`.

Comment: Can you also share the error as plain text instead of image?

Comment: root@e021ed898c81:/# redis-benchmark -c 1 -r 100000 -q
PING_INLINE: 27122.32 requests per second
PING_BULK: 30778.70 requests per second
Error: Server closed the connection
[1]+  Killed                  redis-server

Comment: Are you meaning this one?